# For any $w ∈ V$ , show that $w ∈ W$ iff $∃ g(t) ∈ P(F)$ such that $w = g(T)v$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let V be a vector space over a field $F, T \in L(V )$; $v \in V \setminus \{0\}$ and $W = \langle v \rangle_T$ . For any $w \in V$ , show that $w ∈ W$ iff $\exists g(t) \in P(F)$ such that $w = g(T)v$

I'm stumped and not sure where to start. Would someone be kind enough to guide me through this?

Comment: What are $\langle v \rangle_T$ and $P(F)$?

Comment: @SquiresMcGee Just write the definition of $\langle v\rangle_T$.