# how can g(T) be a polynomial when $T$ is a transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T be a linear operator on a vector space V

Let $v\neq 0 \in V$ and $W$ be the T-cyclic subspace of $V$ generated by $v$

$\forall w \in V$, prove that $w\in W$ iff $\exists $  a polynomial $g(t):w=g(T)(v)$

---

Following online solutions *wrote it on my own words*

$\Rightarrow$] (if $w\in W \Rightarrow \exists g(t)=g(T)v$ )

$W$ is T cyclic  generated by v so 
 $$W= \{ v,T(v),\dots ,T^k (V)\} $$
since $w \in W$ $$ w = c_0*v +c_1 T(v)+\dots c_k T^k(v)$$

**[Confused here can say that]** So, $w=g(T)(v)$

guessing $g(T)=c+c_1T+\dots +c_kT$ and we have that $w \in W$ 
$$ w = (c_0 +c_1 T+\dots c_k T^k)(v)$$

$\Leftarrow $]($\exists g(t)=G(T)v \rightarrow w\in W$) 
obviously $w$ is a linear combo of the basis of $W$ so $w \in W$

---

> **Question boils down** to how can g(T) be a polynomial when $T$ is a transformation?

(oh yeah, this question is technaqually a duplicate there is the exact question without any input  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471443/for-any-w-%E2%88%88-v-show-that-w-%E2%88%88-w-iff-%E2%88%83-gt-%E2%88%88-pf-such-that-w-gtv))

Comment: It's just notation, and you have understood it correctly. The polynomial $g$ is just the function that sends a number $x$ to the number $c_0 + \cdots + c_k x^k$. Since multiplication and linear combinations make sense for linear transformations, it makes sense, and is convenient, to go ahead and write $g(T)$ to mean $c_0 I + c_1 T + \cdots  +C_k T^k$, which is an operator on $V$. So $g$ is a polynomial, but $g(T)$ is a linear transformation which can be thought of the image of $T$ under the polynomial $g$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have a typo which should be replaced to 
$W={\rm span}(\{v,T(v),T^2(v),\ldots\})$. So if $w\in W$, then we can write
$w=c_0v+c_1T(v)+\cdots+c_kT^k(v)$ for some scalars $c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_k\in \mathbb{F}$ and 
$c_k\neq 0$. Thus we can apply the polynomial $g(t)=c_0+c_1t+\cdots+c_kt^k\in \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{F})$ to obtain the identity 
\begin{align*}
w&=c_0{\rm id}(v)+c_1T(v)+\cdots+c_kT^k(v)\\
&=\left(c_0{\rm id}+c_1T+\cdots+c_kT^k\right)(v)\\
&=g(T)(v).
\end{align*}